# Creating a 2 dimensional linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

For an assignment we have to implement a two dimensional linked list in C.
My idea was to create several linked lists on their own and link their heads together.

This is the code I came up with, which does not work unfortunately.
When I try to traverse the result starting from the tree node, there is nothing printed.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on whats wrong with that code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct cell{
    int value;
    struct cell *next;
};

struct head {
   int value;
   struct head *next;
   struct cell *cells;
};

struct head *current_head, *new_head;
struct cell *current_cell, *new_cell;

int i;
int j;
void grid_init(int num_rows,int num_columns){
    for (i=0; i<num_rows-1;i++) {
        struct cell * current_cell = (struct cell* ) malloc (sizeof(struct cell));
        current_head->cells = current_cell;
        for (j=0; j<num_columns-1; j++) {
            struct cell* new_cell = (struct cell* ) malloc (sizeof(struct cell));
            current_cell->next = new_cell;
            current_cell->value=j;
            current_cell = new_cell;
        }
        struct head* new_head = (struct head *) malloc (sizeof(struct head));
        current_head->next = new_head;
        current_head->value=i;
        current_head = new_head;
    }
};



void print_grid(){
    struct head* temp = current_head;
    struct cell* tempcell = current_cell;
    while(temp->next!=NULL){
        tempcell = temp->cells;
        while(tempcell->next!=NULL){
            tempcell = temp->cells;
            printf("%i", tempcell->value);
            tempcell = tempcell->next;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
};

int main(){
    current_head = (struct head *) malloc (sizeof(struct head));
    int a=5;
    int b=5;
    grid_init(a,b);
    print_grid();
};
```

Comment: `two dimansional linked list` - so there is one list, with elements, And each of the elements of the first list is a head of another list. In that another list are elements. I would go with `struct node { int value; struct node *next, *prev; };` and `struct node_1 { struct node *head; struct node_1 *next, *prev; };` - each `struct node_1` has a head of `struct node` list. Then you have `struct node_1 *head` as the head of the list. || In your code `root->next=NULL;` in `main()` is invalid - `root` is initialized with NULL, there is no `root->next`.

Comment: Why do you expect anything to be printed?

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom I edited the code. Still no print.